# cannot get response from Bokeh RadioButtonGroup

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter, bokeh

I am trying to understand how to use interactivity in RadioButtonGroup using Bokeh and CustomJS with a Python function. I have tweaked [the example provided at the Bokeh site](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html) for plotting y=x^f. Instead of using a slider for the power f, I would like to toggle between two powers, f=0.5 and f=0.2. I have followed the manual and inserted RadioButtonGroup in my code using Jupyter notebook. The buttons are showing and responsive, but I am unable to get any callback response out of toggling the buttons.

Any help will be appreciated.

```html
from math import pi

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Slider, TextInput, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_notebook

output_notebook()

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

def callback(source=source, input1=input1, window=None):
    data = source.data
    m= input1.active
    if m==0:
        f=.5
    else:
        f=2
        
    x, y = data['x'], data['y']
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y[i] = window.Math.pow(x[i], f)
    source.trigger('change')

input1 = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["power = .5", "power = 2."], active=0)

input1.button_type="success"
input1.js_on_change('active', CustomJS.from_py_func(callback))

layout = column(input1, plot)

show(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not make  `bokeh.models.RadioButtonGroup` generate a callback, but with `bokeh.models.RadioGroup` I can (I'm using bokeh version 0.12.4 Maybe a newer version facilitates `RadioButtonGroup` to generate a callback). Also, you are referencing `input1` before declaring it. It's not needed as input of your callback function, inside you can use `cb_obj`. See:

```
import bokeh
import bokeh.plotting

bokeh.io.output_notebook()

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

def callback(source=source, window=None):
    data = source.data
    m = cb_obj.active
    if m==0:
        f=.5
    else:
        f=2

    x, y = data['x'], data['y']
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y[i] = window.Math.pow(x[i], f)
    source.trigger('change')

input1 = bokeh.models.RadioGroup(labels=["power = .5", "power = 2."],active=0,
                   callback=bokeh.models.CustomJS.from_py_func(callback))

layout = bokeh.layouts.column(input1, plot)

bokeh.io.show(layout)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. BTW, re-positioning the input1 declaration made the RadioButtonGroup work fine in Bokeh 0.12.5.